# Remove logo greeting and fix scrollbar position, after returning to home view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation

When you first visit [this website](http://lado-furniture.com.ua/#/) you can see logo hello(lado soft furniture) and animation of scrollbar - I need to run this animation only once.
After that if you come to some category and then will return to home view(ГЛАВНАЯ) - animation of logo hello and scrollbar will be running again.

```
// MY HOME VIEW
<div id='logo-hello'>
  <img src='http://lado-furniture.com.ua/sources/images/logo-hello-big.png'>
  <img src='http://lado-furniture.com.ua/sources/images/logo-hello-small.png'> 
</div>
<div class='sliderContainer'>
  <div class='iosSlider'>
    <div class='slider'>
      <div id='advertising1' class='item'></div>
      <div id='advertising2' class='item'></div>
      <div id='advertising3' class='item'></div>
      <div id='advertising4' class='item'></div>
      <div id='advertising5' class='item'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id='home-scrollbar-holder'></div>

  // H O M E  C O N T R O L L E R
  app.controller('homeController', function ($scope){

    // align logo hello vertically through the middle
    $('#logo-hello img:first').load(function(){
      var logoBigHeight = $(this).height();
      $('#logo-hello').css({ 
        'height'    : logoBigHeight + 'px',
        'margin-top': '-' + (logoBigHeight / 2) + 'px'
      });
    });

    // appearance of logo hello, logo and menu
    $('#logo-hello img:first').animate({opacity: '1'}, 1000, function (){
      $('#logo-hello img:last').animate({opacity: '1'}, 1000, function (){
        $('#logo-hello').delay(1000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000, function (){ 
          $(this).remove();

          $('#logo-holder').animate({top:'0'});
          $('#menu-wrap').animate({bottom:'0'});
          $('#home-scrollbar-holder').animate({bottom:'60px'});
        });
      });
    });

    // slider settings
    $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
      //autoSlide: true,
      desktopClickDrag: true,
      snapToChildren: true,
      scrollbarDrag: true,
      scrollbarContainer: '#home-scrollbar-holder',
      scrollbarMargin: 0,
      scrollbarHeight: '10px',
      scrollbarBorderRadius: 1,
      scrollbarOpacity: 1
    });

  }); // end homeController
```

I tried something like :

```
$('.category-holder:first').on('click', function (){
  $('#logo-hello').remove();
  $('#home-scrollbar-holder').css('bottom', '60px');
});
```

How can I remove the animation of logo hello and fix scrollbar position after returning to home view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a global variable and do a check in your `homeController` after the first set of `animations` set the variable to `true`

e.g.

```
  var animationRun = false;
  // H O M E  C O N T R O L L E R
  app.controller('homeController', function ($scope){

    // align logo hello vertically through the middle
    $('#logo-hello img:first').load(function(){
      var logoBigHeight = $(this).height();
      $('#logo-hello').css({ 
        'height'    : logoBigHeight + 'px',
        'margin-top': '-' + (logoBigHeight / 2) + 'px'
      });
    });
    if(!animationRun){
    // appearance of logo hello, logo and menu
    $('#logo-hello img:first').animate({opacity: '1'}, 1000, function (){
      $('#logo-hello img:last').animate({opacity: '1'}, 1000, function (){
        $('#logo-hello').delay(1000).animate({opacity: '0'}, 1000, function (){ 
          $(this).remove();
          animationRun = true; // <<-- Here 
          $('#logo-holder').animate({top:'0'});
          $('#menu-wrap').animate({bottom:'0'});
          $('#home-scrollbar-holder').animate({bottom:'60px'});
        });
      });
    });
    }

    // slider settings
    $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
      //autoSlide: true,
      desktopClickDrag: true,
      snapToChildren: true,
      scrollbarDrag: true,
      scrollbarContainer: '#home-scrollbar-holder',
      scrollbarMargin: 0,
      scrollbarHeight: '10px',
      scrollbarBorderRadius: 1,
      scrollbarOpacity: 1
    });

  }); // end homeController
```

Comment: almost, scrlbar have the initial position, but approach is cool!

Comment: I can't seem to see a scroll bar on the `#home` page?

Comment: after first come to home pg it has position bottom -10px and after appearance of alogo hello it change it to bottom 60px(scrollbar is under the menu). after returning to home pg the scrolbar has initial position bottom -10px

Comment: but using your solution - I guess I know how to fix it, tnx